# lock free BulkCollector and FatalExecutionEngineError exception

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I'm working on a lock free stack and queue data stracture where I can place as many add items as I want and collect all the items in a single call, I think my design is solid and it is working as expected until I started to recive an unexpected exception which I thought is impossible in a pure C# envirement:

Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' has detected a problem Additional Information: The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x6caf6ac7, on thread 0x16f0. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.

I cant seem to be able to find way is it happening and would like to know if someone can direct me to the cause of the error:

This is the implemention of the stackbulkcollector:

```
public class StackBulkCollector<T> : IBulkCollector<T>
{        
    class Node
    {
        public T value;
        private bool m_isSet;
        private Node m_prev;

        public Node(T data)
        {
            value = data;
        }

        public Node()
        {                
        }

        public Node Prev
        {
            set
            {
                m_prev = value;
                m_isSet = true;
            }

            get
            {
                if (!m_isSet)
                {
                    SpinWait s = new SpinWait();
                    while (!m_isSet)
                    {
                        s.SpinOnce();
                    }
                }

                return m_prev;
            }
        }
    }

    class Enumerable : IEnumerable<T>
    {
        private Node m_last;

        public Enumerable(Node last)
        {
            m_last = last;
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new Enumerator(m_last);
        }

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new Enumerator(m_last);
        }
    }

    class Enumerator : IEnumerator<T>
    {
        private readonly Node m_last;
        private Node m_current;

        public Enumerator(Node last)
        {
            var node = new Node();
            m_current = m_last = node;
            node.Prev = last;
        }

        public T Current
        {
            get { return m_current.value; }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

        object System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get { return this; }
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            if (m_current == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            m_current = m_current.Prev;
            return m_current != null;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            m_current = m_last;
        }
    }

    private Node m_last;

    public void Add(T data)
    {
        var node = new Node(data);
        node.Prev = Interlocked.Exchange(ref m_last, node);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetBulk()
    {
        var last = Interlocked.Exchange(ref m_last, null);
        return new Enumerable(last);
    }
}
```

And this is the tester program I use to test it:

```
class Program
{
    public static readonly int UseThreads = 4;
    public static readonly TimeSpan Duration = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,3);

    public static long[] AddedItems = new long[UseThreads];

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IBulkCollector<TestData> bulkCollector = new QueuedBulkCollector<TestData>();
        while (true)
        {
            using (var countdownEvent = new CountdownEvent(UseThreads + 1))
            {
                var results = new Dictionary<int, List<TestData>>();
                if (bulkCollector is QueuedBulkCollector<TestData>)
                {
                    bulkCollector = new StackBulkCollector<TestData>();
                    Console.WriteLine("Starting StackBulkCollector Test");
                }
                else
                {
                    bulkCollector = new StackBulkCollector<TestData>();
                    Console.WriteLine("Starting QueuedBulkCollector Test");
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < UseThreads; i++)
                {
                    results[i] = new List<TestData>();
                    Thread t = new Thread(PushTestData);
                    t.Start(new object[] {i, bulkCollector, countdownEvent});
                }

                var start = DateTime.Now;
                Thread readerThred = new Thread(() =>
                                                    {
                                                        while ((DateTime.Now - start) <
                                                               (Duration - new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100)))
                                                        {
                                                            foreach (var testData in bulkCollector.GetBulk())
                                                            {
                                                                results[testData.Id].Add(testData);
                                                            }
                                                            //Console.WriteLine("Doing Some Read {0}", currBulk.Count);
                                                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
                                                        }
                                                        countdownEvent.Signal();
                                                    });
                readerThred.Start();
                countdownEvent.Wait();

                var lastBulk = bulkCollector.GetBulk().ToList();
                foreach (var testData in lastBulk)
                {
                    results[testData.Id].Add(testData);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Doing Last Read {0}", lastBulk.Count);

                long[] value = new long[UseThreads];
                long totalCount = 0;
                int errorCount = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < UseThreads; i++)
                {
                    value[i] = AddedItems[i];
                    totalCount += value[i];
                    Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} Push {1} Items", i, value[i]);
                    var verifyArray = results[i].OrderBy(p => p.Value).ToList();
                    if (verifyArray.Count != value[i])
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Not Working Count miss match");
                        errorCount++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var expected = 0;
                        foreach (var testData in verifyArray)
                        {
                            if (expected != testData.Value)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("NotWorking");
                                errorCount++;
                            }
                            expected++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Done Total Push {0} with {1} errors.", totalCount.ToString("#,##0") , errorCount);
                if (errorCount != 0)
                {
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void PushTestData(object o)
    {
        object[] parms = o as object[];
        int id = (int)parms[0];
        IBulkCollector<TestData> bulkCollector = (IBulkCollector<TestData>)parms[1];
        CountdownEvent endEvetn = (CountdownEvent)parms[2];
        AddedItems[id] = 0;
        var start = DateTime.Now;
        while ((DateTime.Now - start) < Duration)
        {
            bulkCollector.Add(new TestData() { Id = id, Value = AddedItems[id]});
            AddedItems[id]++;
        }

        endEvetn.Signal();
    }
}
```

Any advice will be most welcome.

Comment: What runtime? x86 or x64? Does it also occur in release mode?

Comment: Is there a stacktrace in the exception?

Comment: I run the program on a 64 bit windows and from a x86 console application,

Comment: i run the same program on my home machine AMD AthlonII250 and on my work computer Intel CoreI5, and cant seem to be able to reproduce the problem in the Intel machine, i dont think there is a stack trace and i dont think it is relvent if i have a memory curruption some place in the code, when i will get home i will repreduce the error and publish any stack trace it will give, since the error is not reproducing in my intel machine im starting to think there is an hardware issue with my amd machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, A defective memory module was the cause of the problem, it has been replaced and the problem was solved.